# Fit the bootstrap collapse panel on same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap collapse panel and I'm having trouble fitting the panel on the same line as the label.

Basically when there are more than one company, I would like to show it as shown in my example. If there's another way or better way of doing it, please let me know

Here's an example of what is happening

http://www.bootply.com/TliniBg50r

Thank you

Comment: is [this](http://www.bootply.com/z519KC22Mf) okay ?

Comment: That kind of works, just wondering if there's a way to do this without using columns and rows, I tried to use input-group and form-group but does not seem to be helping.

Comment: Even form-group uses columns

Comment: Thank you @Raviteja for your comments, I realized I didn't needed all those bell and whisles so I removed some divs and seem to work for now

http://www.codeply.com/go/CAbHSSosRd